# Enzyme 3.11.0 how to test for a class selector not existing on the page

Tags: javascript, enzyme

I have a Reactjs Driven project where an element has a conditional logic to show/not show.

With this line, I can find the element when the condition is to show.

```js
expect(wrapper.exists(".class-selector")).to.equal(true);
```

However I have tried a number of different things to validate it doesn't show under a certain condition, and all I get is errors from the Enzyme. The latest attempt being.

```js
expect(wrapper.find(".class-selector").length).to.equal(0);
```

Through manual means of visually inspecting it through a browser, I can verify that when the conditions change, they hide/show respectively. So I know its working as expected. I just can't get Enzyme to confirm that for me.

**EDIT** Including Error message of the above example.

```
>> FAIL: should not show element ID element_wrapper (1ms)
    AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 0
      at Assertion.assertEqual  <__intern/browser_modules/chai/chai.js:776:12>
      at Assertion.ctx.<computed> [as equal]  <__intern/browser_modules/chai/chai.js:4192:25>
      at Test.test  <build/js/webpack+accountant-pap-ui:/test/unit/widgets/globalBenefitsDashboard/components/FeaturedBenefit/FeaturedBenefitTest.js:181:60>
      at <__intern/lib/Test.js:191:24>
      at <__intern/browser_modules/dojo/Promise.js:156:41>
      at runCallbacks  <__intern/browser_modules/dojo/Promise.js:19:22>
      at <__intern/browser_modules/dojo/Promise.js:103:21>
      at run  <__intern/browser_modules/dojo/Promise.js:51:33>
      at CallbackQueue.drain  <__intern/browser_modules/dojo/CallbackQueue.js:39:35>
      at MutationObserver.<anonymous>  <__intern/browser_modules/dojo/nextTick.js:52:27>
>> 1/10 tests failed
```

Comment: Could you please specify the error? Or even better provide an example?

Comment: It says the element is added to the dom. Are you sure the "show confition" is evaluated to false during the test? How do you hide/show the element, thorugh CSS or conditional rendering?

Comment: conditional rendering

Comment: And this is the only element on the page with this css class? Strange... Can you show me an example?

Comment: correct, the scope of the element is an informational banner that shows conditionally to specific tiers of the service. When you are on a tier that doesn't contain the need for that banner the DOM doesn't even render the banner.

Comment: I cannot help without a dummy example. Can you reproduce the issue with different js/html but the same logic?

Comment: unfortunately no, not without spending a couple of days to rebuild it for the concept only (primarily due to what is being tested is considered "proprietary". However I can say through the discussion with you brief as its been you did point something out, that made me go hmmm so I am looking in to that, and while the test works locally, in the staging environment, the data subset may be different. We shall see, thank you :-)